# How to slide a div out from the right?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure where to begin.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Not looking for code, just guidance.

When a link is clicked, I want a panel (the height of the screen) to slide out from the right to about 50% of the window.

How can I accomplish something like this?

If I just do slidetoggle, it goes up/down.  But not sure how to come out from the right side of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use jQuery's animate function on the elements width.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:0%;"></div>
```

On click:

```
$('#mydiv').animate({'width':'50%'});
```

You will probably get better results using some positioning and animating the element's "left" property, but [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used to slide a div to the right and delete it.  You might want to take out the remove.

```
$('#'+val).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500, function() {
            $('#'+val).remove();
        });
```

Comment: Looks like that hides the element... I believe he is trying to make a hidden element become visible with a sliding action.

Comment: Seems like he'd prefer to be guided towards a solution?